# Потерялся в алгоритме вычисления разницы

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, delphi

В общем есть *DataSet* с набором вот таких данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить из них разность *СКО1* **СМЕЖНЫХ** дат, по которой я строю график. Например если я нахожусь на строке 15.11.2017 то это будет 0,039-0,026.

Вопросов бы не возникало бы, если при одинаковых датах не нужно было складывать *СКО1* с *СКО3* и с суммы обратно получать разность, например когда находишься на дате 01.12.2017, то это будет 0,005+0,016-0,010.
Я просто теряюсь в какой переменной у меня уменьшаемое, а в каком вычитаемое… и заносятся они все время в разные переменные, нужно ставить дополнительные флаги... это просто ппп…
Алгоритм как бы не очень ясен

Я уже не знаю, может нужно организовать дополнительный массив уменьшаемых, и вычитаемых, и когда они сформируются (значения при одинаковых датах) тогда только вычислять разность.

Разности конечно для каждых *ID* свои.

Comment: "заносятся они все время в разные переменные" - сами, что ли?

Comment: надеюсь данный датасет не только для этой цели нужен? ибо данную задачу куда проще решить прямо в запросе.

Comment: @ Igor/  не я сначало формирую вычитаемое, потом следующая дата - формирую уменшаемое, потом при следующей дате, когда нужно вычитать у меня получается в одной переменной не то значение. в общем с алгоритмом проблема..

Comment: @Konstantin78 дак вы возьмите лист бумаги и составьте алгоритм, а потом уже к программированию переходите.

Comment: Почему для 15.11.2017 мы берем разность 13.11.2017 - 12.11.2017, а для 01.12.2017 вы вычитаете 01.12.2017 - 30.11.2017

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, ну мне же нужно узнать насколько увеличилось значение именно за 1 день, я выше писал, что нужно получать разность только смежных дат (например 13.11 и 12.11; 30.11 и 29.11 и т.д). Если дата пропускается, как например 13.11 и 15.11 то мы ее не учитываем

Comment: Что такое `смежные даты`?

Comment: я имею ввиду, даты между которыми разница 1 день

Comment: Ладно наверное всеже внести некоторые правки в запрос всеже придется и попробовать сложить СКО с одинаковыми датами в нем. Не хотелось бы "select max(DATE_CONTROL), SUM(COALESCE(CKO1,0) + COALESCE(CKO3,0)) as VALUE1, COUNT(*) AS VALUE2 from table1
GROUP BY FLOOR(CAST(DATE_CONTROL AS FLOAT))
ORDER BY DATE_CONTROL"

Comment: Следующий запрос: "select max(DATE_CONTROL) as DATE_CONTROL, SUM(COALESCE(CKO1,0) + COALESCE(CKO3,0)) as SUM_CKO, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_CALCULATION, CALC_ID from MEASUREMENT
where ORGANIZATION_ID = 58 and CALC_ID in (select ID from CALCULATION where CHART_ENABLE = 1)
GROUP BY cast(DATE_CONTROL as date), CALC_ID" --  выдает результат " https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfcp59zzviiit53/null%20in%20table.png?dl=0 " который мне капельку не подходит, тем что допустим в 07.11.2017 записывает "0", а нужно "null" (это нужно там где дата одна и "СКО1 = null"). Как мне этот запрос переделать?